# Vector image is stretched

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I need to make a layout like this here form:

[image]

I use vector (dialog.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="692.6dp"
    android:height="312.4dp"
    android:viewportWidth="692.6"
    android:viewportHeight="312.4">

    <path
        android:fillColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:pathData="M 1.2 1.1 H 692.5 V 285.1 H 1.2 V 1.1 Z" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:pathData="M 595.9 285.1 L 623.6 285.1 L 596 312.8 L 568.1 285.1 Z" />
</vector>
```

Then:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dp">

        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="400dp"
            android:rotation="100"
            android:background="@drawable/dialog"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Test"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:textSize="25pt"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

But the image is stretched and looks not nice. In addition, vector requires API level 21, my app min API is 15. How can I make the layout of this form in another way?

Comment: An other way  to make layout of this form is to use drawable images.

Comment: @OsamaAftab without images it is impossible to do it?

Comment: Why do you want to do without images?

Comment: What you are looking for is a nine-patch drawable, it works in versions before 21 http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch